# Overcollecting fees, over collecting fees, or over-collecting fees?

Tags: open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Should "overcollecting" and "undercollecting" be closed in the sentence below? Or should they be open or hyphenated.  The hyphenation guide from the Chicago Manual of Style seems to indicate they should be closed; however, I cannot find any good examples that make me feel confident about about leaving them closed. Also, my spellchecker marks them as incorrect. I do not have the option of rewording the sentence to avoid the problem.

This may result in the Program overcollecting or undercollecting fees from local residents who participate in the Program.

Comment: I would suggest that you consult the authorities responsible for whatever your sentence will appear in. Personally, I would write: *"This may result in the Program over- or undercollecting fees from the local residents who participate."* ++ If the Chicago manual of style does not make you feel confident, there are probably other style manuals. The point is that hyphenation is often an evolutionary point between two words and one word. Of its nature, the transition is vague.

Comment: The only reason *overcollecting* is marked as incorrect is because it doesn't exist as a unique word in the dictionary. That doesn't mean it's wrong. It's formed from an acknowledged prefix and an actual word. In short, it's still grammatical, even though it doesn't have a distinct dictionary entry. (It would be silly to have an entry for every possible *over[word]* combination that isn't used often enough in its own right.)

Comment: Who says you cannot rewrite it? "...program collecting fees that are too high or low from participating residents."